# Using SUMIFS with one array criteria and other non array criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling with using the SUMIFS function with one variable array criteria.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Opportunity List'!$AO$3:$AO$711,'Opportunity List'!$AM$3:$AM$711,">="&DATE(YEAR(C137),MONTH(C137),1),'Opportunity List'!$AM$3:$AM$711,"<="&DATE(YEAR(C137),MONTH(C137),31),'Opportunity List'!$K$3:K$711,"{"&F145&"}"))
```

As you can see, the above formula has two criteria sets that are not arrays and work perfectly, however when I add in the last criteria set nothing happens.

F145 in this case is a string that changes based on check boxes.
Such as  ' "Budgetary","FFP" '   or    ' "Budgetary","FFP","ROM" '

I have also tried formatting the variable string as a conditional array.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Opportunity List'!$AO$3:$AO$711,'Opportunity List'!$AM$3:$AM$711,">="&DATE(YEAR(C138),MONTH(C138),1),'Opportunity List'!$AM$3:$AM$711,"<="&DATE(YEAR(C138),MONTH(C138),31),'Opportunity List'!$K$3:K$711,PDArray))
```

PDArray being the array that changes. Still to no avail.

Is Is there a simple syntax error I am missing? Or is there nonfunctionality due to only one of the three criteria sets being an array and the SUMIFS output array is not fully defined?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. if `F145` is one of several string, why not use `...,'Opportunity List'!$K$3:K$711,F$145))` ?

Comment: F145 is not an array but a string.  And as such this will not work,  You will need to separate the string into its parts, into individual cells.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad 'Opportunity List'!$K$3:K$711
is a column that can have one of 5 different values. Budgetary and ROM being two of them. 

I am trying to sum column AO depending on the month - first two criteria sets, and a user defined choice of any or all values in column K. - the part im having trouble with.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you, I guess I was trying to keep things too aesthetic and use only one column. I added a second column with the user selected choices and put that in the formula and it worked. and I now know an array is not defined by its format. 
Thank you for your help,

Comment: just an fyi, there is a method to turn a comma delimited list into an array with a formula, but it is long. for example if your comma delimited string was in E5 then using this: `INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E5,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(E5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E5,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),)` as an array formula would return an array to the parent function.  You must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.